# Is it possible to back up a PS3 via a network share?

Tags: ps3

Is it possible to use the Sony built in PS3 backup utility to do it's backups over a network share, or is it only possible through a direct attached USB storage medium?

Comment: Great question.  I never tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not possible. It's only possible through USB.

Comment: This is unfortunate :(